# App menu option color

Tags: java, android, menu, items

Hello I want to change my app menu option (black text on white Background instead of white text on black Backgroud ) [image]

Here is my menu xlm file

```html
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.androidsrc.tower.Liste1">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings" />
    <item android:id="@+id/aide"
        android:title="@string/aide" />
</menu>
```

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your menu.xml to this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
         android:title="@string/action_settings" />
    <item android:id="@+id/aide"
         android:title="@string/aide" />
</menu>
```

In your styles.xml file add the following to your base app theme

```
 <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/CMOptionsMenu</item>
```

and then add the following `style`to the file

```
<style name="CMOptionsMenu" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ListPopupWindow">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
</style>
```

In the AndroidManifest.xml remember to add the following to your `application`

```
android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme"
```

Comment: Is there an other issu becauce android:actionBarPopupTheme requieres API level 21 and current min sdk is 16

Comment: @pape I changed some of the code in order to try to make it compatible with your sdk level, hope it works now.

Comment: look at my comment below please

Comment: @pape try now, as you can see I changed the parent

Comment: I have this error , U can see in the comment below the xlm file
C:\pape\TPIv M1\app\src\main\res\values\styles.xml
Error:(3, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionOverflowMenuStyle'.

Comment: @pape Check my answer again, I had forgotten to mention that I also changed that name :). It's now `android:popupMenuStyle`

Comment: now there is no error but after running the app the menu option still like de default menu (black background ant white text)

Comment: Maybe I should add something in the menu.xlm ?

Comment: @pape Does it not work after adding the Manifest code?

Comment: @pape Check my answer again, I actually changed your menu.xml file too as I do not see the point of your `tools` and `app` parameters. Based on the image you provided my code should be enough to attain that design.

Comment: look at my comment below please

Comment: @pape Weird. Try changing the `parent` of your `AppBaseTheme` to `android:Theme.Holo.Light`.

Comment: Ok I'm trying that, I told you after

Comment: oh yeah its work!  thank you very very much you save me thank you I so happy

Comment: @pape Glad it finally worked. I advice you to delete your posts (answers) that you posted in order to show me the errors (as they don't add any value) and could you please mark this answer as the accepted one:)

Comment: @pepe No problem, I'm happy I could help :)